# What does the result numbers mean in Tensorflow text_classification

Tags: python, tensorflow

Tensorflow text_classification:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification

There are only two classes in this text_classification example,

```
Label 0 corresponds to neg
Label 1 corresponds to pos
```

But the following prediction values neither `0` nor `1`:

```
examples = [
  "The movie was great!",
  "The movie was okay.",
  "The movie was terrible..."
]

export_model.predict(examples)

array([[0.5921171 ],
       [0.41369876],
       [0.33293992]], dtype=float32)
```

The result of "`The movie was great!`" is `0.5921171`, but what does that mean?

Does it mean `positive` for `value >= 0.5` and `negative` for `value < 0.5`?

It should predict it as something like:

```
array([[1 ],
       [1],
       [0]], dtype=float32)
```

At the end of that link, there is an exercise:

**Exercise: multi-class classification on Stack Overflow questions**

The threshold 0.5 is not work for multi-class classification on Stack Overflow questions because there are total 4 labels & classes in this exercise.

```
for i in range(len(raw_train_ds.class_names)):
    print("Label: {}, Class Name: {}".format(i, raw_train_ds.class_names[i]))

Label: 0, Class Name: csharp
Label: 1, Class Name: java
Label: 2, Class Name: javascript
Label: 3, Class Name: python
```

I'm using the same examples array for prediction:

```
examples = [
  "The movie was great!",
  "The movie was okay.",
  "The movie was terrible..."
]

export_model.predict(examples)

array([[0.52356344, 0.4763114 , 0.54468685, 0.4438951 ],
       [0.52287084, 0.48242405, 0.5407451 , 0.4425373 ],
       [0.5221944 , 0.4766879 , 0.5448719 , 0.4454918 ]], dtype=float32)
```

How to set threshold for the `four` `multi-class classification` on Stack Overflow questions?

**I think it is not related to threshold.**

Comment: If your threshold is set at 0.5, then yes, that is what it means..

Comment: The original link doesn't set any threshold like 0.5.

Comment: I am aware of that..you need to set it explicitly.

Comment: If you search the word threshold in the link you gave, you will find where the threshold is set.

Comment: Also, check the source code of `tf.keras.metrics.binary_accuracy` --> https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/d8fcb9d4d4dad45080ecfdd575483653028f8eda/keras/metrics.py#L4013

Comment: I added the StackOverflow dataset Exercise to the end of the post, I think it is not related to the threshold. Please check the updated post content.

Comment: You are confused. You use different loss functions for binary class classification and multi-class classification. No one said you need to defined a threshold for multi-class classification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a threshold that whenever you get a value greater than it it is considered as positive, otherwise it considers it as negative. In your example to get [1,1,0] a threshold of 0.4 for example gives the right predictions.

Comment: To choose a good threshold for your task you need to try different threshold values and pick the one that gives you best results.

Comment: Thank you, but where to set the threshold?

Comment: You define it wherever you want, and change every value which is greater than the threshold as 1 or positive, and values less than the threshold as 0 or negative.

Comment: I added the StackOverflow dataset Exercise to the end of the post, I think it is not related to the threshold. Please check the updated post content. How to set threshold if it is multi-class?

Comment: I'm confused right now, in the beginning you say that you have a binary classification task. Usually with binary classification tasks you have the output layer produce output values between 0 and 1, and you apply a specific threshold to map these values into predictions. But now you say that you have multi classes (which does not look at all like what you first ask), and this requires different methods. For example you can train k classifiers (k equals to the number of classes) and apply activation methods like the softmax to assign the result class.

Comment: But based on the guide of that link, it doesn't require to change the activation method to softmax, please search this from that link: To complete this exercise, you should modify this notebook to work with the Stack Overflow dataset by making the following modifications

Comment: I checked the link, you make the last dense layer of size 4, which is one for each class. Which typically means that you are making 4 different classifiers as I said earlier, the output of each one equals the output of a binary classifier which means how much the current input belongs to the this class (this is called one-vs-all method). The output here is logits, so to make a prediction you have to apply methods like softmax to get the best fitting class of yours.